# How to change the response format depending on the data sent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing some controllers to render reports and here is my problem:

The user open a page with a form which let it change the download format and the date of the report.

The download format is set trough a select input.

When the user press the button I want to response depending on the selected format.

The problem is that it's specified trough the url. So trying to do something like:

```
case format
when "xlsx" then format.xlsx{...}
when "html" then format.html{...}
...
end
```

doesn't work because rails or the browser (I'm not sure) expects an html response.

I've though of two options:

1. Change the url of the form `onsubmit` which makes the application more dependent on javascript. Or.
2. `redirect_to url + ".#{params[:download_format]}"`

The second way looks better to me but I need to pass the `:report_date` in the url and I can't find the way to do it.

I've tried this:

```
url = my_custom_url_path
redirect_to url + ".#{params[:download_format]}", :date_format => params[:date_format]
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

In the form:

```
<%= f.select :download_format, { "xlsx" => "xlsx, "Online" => "html" } %>
```

In the controller:

```
def action
    if download_format = params[:download_format].delete
        redirect_to my_action_path(options.merge( :format => download_format ) ) and return
    end
    # do some logic here
    respond_to do |format|
        format.xlsx{...}
        format.html{...}
    end
end
```